# JSON files does not contain all the results in AWS Lambda using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently working on a project using AWS S3, Rekognition and Lambda. I'm writing in NodeJS and created a working solution to what I want to achieve. The workflow in short is: an image of a face is loaded onto a S3 bucket, then the 'searchFacesByImage' API is called to see if that face has been indexed to the Master collection in the past. If it is a new face, the result will be false, and the 'indexFaces' API is called to index that face to the Master collection. Once that is done, I write the output to 3 separate JSON files that is in the same S3 bucket, called: 'metadata.json', 'indexing.json', 'rekognition.json'.

The 'metadata.json' file only contains the ExternalImageID (that I create myself), the date and time of indexing, the filename that was indexed, and a count that counts how many times that face has been indexed in the past.

The 'indexing.json' file contains the same ExternalImageID, the same data and time of indexing, and the response from the 'searchFacesByImage' API.

The 'rekognition.json' file contains the same ExternalImageID and date and time, as well as the response from the 'indexFaces' API.

The problem comes in that when I load on image at a time, the 3 JSON files will start to populate accordingly, but as soon as I load more than a few (I've tested it with 7) images at the same time, all 7 images will run through the workflow and the response data is written out to each file according to the Cloudwatch logs, but when I actually go to view the JSON files, not all the response data is there for all 7 images. Sometimes the data of 5 images are in the JSON, other times its 4 images. The data doesn't have to be in any specific order, it must just be there. I've also tested it where I uploaded 18 images at once and only the response of 10 images was in the JSON.

I believe the problem comes in that I'm calling the 'getObject' API on the JSON files, then I append the response data to those files, and then I'm calling the 'putObject' API on those JSON files to put them back into the S3 bucket, but while the first image is going through this process, the next image wants to do the same, but there is no file to use the 'getObject' on, because it is busy with the previous image, so then it just skips over the image, although the Cloudwatch logs said I has been added to the files.

I have no idea how to work around this. I believe the answer lies in Asynchronous JavaScript (which I don't know that much of so I have no idea where to begin)

My apologies for the long post. Here is my code below:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: "2006-03-01"});
const rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition();
//const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

let bucket, key;
let dataSaveDate = new Date();

console.log('Loading function');


//-----------------------------------Exports Function---------------------------
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

    console.log(bucket);
    console.log(key);

    searchingFacesByImage(bucket, key);
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Search for a face in an input image
function searchingFacesByImage(bucket, key) {
    let params = {
        CollectionId: "allFaces", 
        FaceMatchThreshold: 95, 
        Image: {
            S3Object: {
                Bucket: bucket, 
                Name: key
            }
        }, 
        MaxFaces: 5
    };

    const searchingFace = rekognition.searchFacesByImage(params, function(err, searchdata) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);    // an error occurred
        } else {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(searchdata, null, '\t'));
            // if data.FaceMatches > 0 : There that face in the image exists in the collection
            if (searchdata.FaceMatches.length > 0) {
                console.log("Face is a match");
            } else {
                console.log("Face is not a match");
                let mapping_id = createRandomId();
                console.log(`Created mapping_id: ${mapping_id}`);

                console.log("Start indexing face to 'allFaces'");
                indexToAllFaces(mapping_id, searchdata, bucket, key);
            }
        }
    });
    return searchingFace;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// If face is not a match in 'allFaces', index face to 'allFaces' using mapping_id
function indexToAllFaces(mapping_id, searchData, bucket, key) {
    let params = {
        CollectionId: "allFaces", 
        DetectionAttributes: ['ALL'], 
        ExternalImageId: mapping_id, 
        Image: {
            S3Object: {
            Bucket: bucket, 
            Name: key
            }
        }
    };
    const indexFace = rekognition.indexFaces(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);    // an error occurred
        } else {
            console.log("INDEXING TO 'allFaces'");
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));

            logAllData(mapping_id, bucket, key, searchData, data);
        }
    });

    return indexFace;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Counting how many times a face has been indexed and logging ALL data in a single log
function logAllData(mapping_id, bucket, key, searchData, data) {
    let params = {
        CollectionId: mapping_id, 
        MaxResults: 20
    };

    const faceDetails = rekognition.listFaces(params, function(err, facedata) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);    // an error occurred
        } else {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(facedata, null, '\t'));

            metadata(mapping_id, bucket, key, facedata);
            indexing(mapping_id, bucket, searchData);
            rekognitionData(mapping_id, bucket, data);
        }
    });

    return faceDetails;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function metadata(mapping_id, bucket, key, faceData) {

    let body = [
        {
            "mapping_id": mapping_id,
            "time": dataSaveDate,
            "image_name": key,
            "indexing_count": faceData.Faces.length - 1
        }
    ];

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, '\t'));

    logData("metadata.json", bucket, body);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function indexing(mapping_id, bucket, searchData) {
    let body = [
        {
            "mapping_id": mapping_id,
            "time": dataSaveDate,
            "IndexingData": searchData
        }    
    ];

    logData("indexing.json", bucket, body);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function rekognitionData(mapping_id, bucket, data) {
    let body = [
        {
            "mapping_id": mapping_id,
            "time": dataSaveDate,
            "rekognition": data
        }    
    ];

    logData("rekognition.json", bucket, body);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function to log all data to JSON files

function logData(jsonFileName, bucket, body) {
    let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: jsonFileName
    };

    const readFile = s3.getObject(params, function(err, filedata) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);        // an error occurred
        } else {
            console.log(`READING ${jsonFileName} CONTENTS`);
            // Read data from 'jsonFileName'
            let raw_content = filedata.Body.toString();
            let content = JSON.parse(raw_content);

            // Add new data to 'jsonFileName'
            content.push(...body);

            // Put new data back into jsonFileName
            s3.putObject(
                {
                    Bucket: bucket,
                    Key: jsonFileName,
                    Body: JSON.stringify(content, null, '\t'),
                    ContentType: "application/json"
                },
                function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(`DATA SAVED TO ${jsonFileName}`);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });

    return readFile;
}

//----------------------------------SCRIPT ENDS---------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you may be right, the problem is Asynchronous calls, i would recommend you to use Async, await to wait for the callback to complete whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When a Node.js Lambda reaches the end of the main thread, it ends all other threads.

To make sure that the lambda does not prematurely terminate those threads, wait until that Promise is complete by using `await`.

The functions `s3.getObject` and `s3.putObject` can be made into a Promise like this:

```
await s3.getObject(params).promise()
await s3.putObject(params).promise()
```